# Do I need to do a free on a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, free

I have a struct defined so I can create it in multiple functions. Do I need to do a 'free' for the struct variable 'sCNArr'?

```
struct sGroupInfo
{
TCHAR *sComputerName;
TCHAR *sMemory;
TCHAR *sHDDCount;
TCHAR *sLogFileName;
DWORD dwOnline;
};

unsigned __stdcall Thread_Restore(void *pComputerName)
{
struct sGroupInfo *sCNArr = NULL;
sCNArr = (struct sGroupInfo *) pComputerName;

std::vector <TCHAR>sCN(128,0);
_tcscpy_s(sCN.data(),sCN.size(),(TCHAR *) sCNArr->sComputerName);

// work done here

free(sCNArr);sCNArr=NULL;
}
```

Comment: are you doing C or C++? Because if you're doing C++ code, then you should avoid using `free()` and a `struct` but instead use a class and call the class destructor to free the memory, if you're doing C code, you should not be using `std::vector`.

Comment: Why would we know if you need to free it? We don't know the rest of the code. It is you who must know if the caller will free the pointer passed to this function or if it's your job to do it inside `Thread_restore`.

Comment: right, I did not know about WIN API specifics

Comment: Not the pointer passed to this function, just the sCNArr, if I should free it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you shall not `free()` instances that have not been allocated through `malloc()`, though it's unclear how the instance has been allocated before being given to that function, though it's unlikely it's been `malloc()`ed as this is C++, which leads me to *2.* ;
2. you should not `free()` C++ objects, but instead call `delete` that will trigger the destructor on instances of objects ;
3. instead of using a struct and calling method over it, like in C, you shall instead use a class that builds nicely the object by associating a constructor, a destructor and a few methods that handles the encapsulated data ;
4. on a more general aspects of things, to answer directly your question, you should release the memory of the objects you create at the same level of function call.

*i.e.* here's how you should handle your instance's lifetime:

```
struct sGroupInfo* foo;
// allocate memory to foo
Thread_Restore(foo);
// release memory for foo
```

so when someone else (which may be you in 6 months) read your code, the object's lifetime is explicit. If you really *need* to release the memory for your object in the function, then your function's name shall reflect it in some way, so it is clear that after your function call, you can't rely on the object being still alive.

edit:

> Not the pointer passed to this function, just the sCNArr, if I should free it?

so here's your code:

```
// you give a pointer to some address in the memory to the function
// so basically let's consider that: pComputerName == 0x42
unsigned __stdcall Thread_Restore(void *pComputerName) {
// you allocate one word of memory here that contains NULL, i.e. sCNArr == 0x00
struct sGroupInfo *sCNArr = NULL;
// then you allocate the value of pComputerName to sCNArr, so sCNArr == 0x42
sCNArr = (struct sGroupInfo *) pComputerName;

// …

// if you free something here, you're deallocating the memory at the address 0x42
// which will end up in undefined behaviour and/or crash if you did not allocate
// the memory using malloc
free(sCNArr);sCNArr=NULL;
}
```

so I guess you shall not.

Comment: Thanks @zmo, that was helpful. Yeah, I just wanted to know if I should free sCNArr from *within* Thread_Restore. I've got *pComputerName handled outside the function, freeing it properly. Others that commented seemed to miss that, or didn't read what my question was asking.